# Make li tag invisible via class

Tags: css, asp.net

I want to the class `dropdown` invisible.  `dropdown` will be used only for specific `li` tags.  I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
.dropdown{
    display:none;
}
```

Is there a way to make this work?  Am I doing something wrong in my CSS?

HTML:

```
<div id="MainNavigation" class="nContainer" name="MainNav" value="MainNavigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="/page.aspx" id="ctl00_top_nav_SOnav" class="dropdown-toggle">page</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="/page1.aspx">page1</a> </li>
                <li><a href="/page2.aspx">page2</a> </li>
                <li><a href="/page3.aspx">page3</a> </li>
                <li><a href="/page4.aspx">page4</a> </li>
                <li><a href="/page5.aspx">page5</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <a id="Homepage" class="navbar-brand" href="somepage.com">
            <img src="/images/aGif.gif?v=24820" alt="someotherpage.com" border="0">
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's always nice to create a fiddle.  My best guess is that it is a specificity issue.  That is, `.dropdown` selector is not detailed enough to override other selectors that come with Bootstrap.  Make the selector more specific (i.e., `#MainNavigation.nContainer[name = "MainNav"] > .nav.navbar-nav > .dropdown`) and see if it works.

Comment: @DRD I had to add the missing bracket, but that worked.  Thank you!  Please post that as an answer.

Comment: You are welcome.  The answer has been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that it is a specificity issue. That is, .dropdown selector is not detailed enough to override other selectors that come with Bootstrap. Make the selector more specific (i.e., `#MainNavigation.nContainer[name = "MainNav"] > .nav.navbar-nav > .dropdown`) and see if it works.

Comment: No worries at all.  :)